# Firebase JWT to django credential login

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

it is possible to login a user from firebase jwt to django if so, what is the tools needed to login a user? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the Firebase Authentication status of the user to authorize them in your Django code. This is indeed possible, and described in the Firebase documentation on [verifying ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). The process is:

1. Retrieve the user's ID token (a JWT indeed) on the client, as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients).
2. On the server, either [use the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) or [use a 3rd party library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library) to verify the ID token.
3. Use the information from the token to determine whether the user is authorized to perform the action they're requesting.